# SQL Server - create value one field from other field in same View table

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I need your help, I don't know exactly name the question. I want create record from other field into one field in the same table of view. but when I create it the value show but from same record.

I have 1 table with 4 field
there are YEAR, PEOPLE, REMAINING, CF

the logic like this :

1. `IF people A in 2014 have remaining value 25 and CF values 0 THEN people A in 2015 will have CF values 6`.
2. `IF Remaining > 6 THEN CF Values only 6, IF Remaining between 0 to 6 THEN CF Values = Remaining, IF Remaining < 0 THEN CF Values 0`
3. `IF values in Current Year will always take from Remaining in Last Year so if People A didn't have remaining in last year, the CF in current year become 0`

Here my code :

```
SELECT  
    A.FiscalYear,
    C.EmployeeName, 
    CASE 
        WHEN A.FiscalYear < 2015 THEN A.Remaining 
        WHEN B_1.daystaken < 0 THEN A.Remaining + ISNULL(B_1.DaysTaken, 0) 
        ELSE A.Entitlement 
    END AS Remaining,
    CASE 
        WHEN A.remaining > 6 THEN 6
        WHEN A.remaining BETWEEN 0 AND 6 THEN A.remaining
        WHEN A.remaining < 0 THEN 0
        ELSE ISNULL(A.remaining,0)
    END AS CF
FROM  dbo.DataLeaveBalance AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.VWLeave_takens AS B_1 
    ON A.FiscalYear = B_1.AffectFY 
    AND A.EmpCode = B_1.EmpCode 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MasterEmployee AS C
    ON A.EmpCode = C.EmpCode
```

```
This the result from my code:

year        people  remain      cf
----------- ------- ----------- -----------
2014        Jackson 14          6
2014        Eva     5           5
2014        Akson   0           0
2015        Jackson 10          6
2015        Eva     10          6
2015        Akson   13          6

I want the result like this:

year        people  remain      cf
----------- ------- ----------- -----------
2014        Jackson 14          0
2014        Eva     5           0
2014        Akson   0           0
2015        Jackson 10          6
2015        Eva     10          5
2015        Akson   13          0
2016        Jackson 10          6
2016        Eva     10          6
2016        Akson   13          6
```

Comment: Your second case statement looks like it might be a bit off. Both Jackson and Eva have > 6 remaining for 2014 (50 and 25), meaning that 6 cf is correct.

Comment: I mean my result for cf will be take from remain value in last year, so if eva in 2014 remain 25 then eva in 2015 for cf will be 25 or six. how I can take like this condition?
when I use case of like that, my result take from same year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have value of the current year available in each row. And your calculation needs access to the value of the previous year.

You could fetch the values of the previous year with a join like FiscalYear-1

Now you have both the current (B_1) and it's previous (B_2) year available on row level and you can use it in your calculation.

```
SELECT  
    *
FROM  dbo.DataLeaveBalance AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.VWLeave_takens AS B_1 
    ON A.FiscalYear = B_1.AffectFY 
    AND A.EmpCode = B_1.EmpCode 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.VWLeave_takens AS B_2
    ON (A.FiscalYear-1) = B_1.AffectFY 
    AND A.EmpCode = B_1.EmpCode 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MasterEmployee AS C
    ON A.EmpCode = C.EmpCode
```

Comment: this is same as my result 
year        people  remain      cf
----------- ------- ----------- -----------
2014        Jackson 50          6
2014        Eva     25          6
2015        Jackson 10          6
2015        Eva     10          6

I want is
CF will show the value from last year (2014) in new year(2015), and the last year become 0 because the year before it(2013) nothing

Comment: I guess misunderstood then, I was under the impression that you were not able to use the calculated value 'remaining' inside as part of another calculated field.

Comment: I've find my answer, using double select in select and double from

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you need to use CTE.

Something like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT  
    A.FiscalYear,
    C.EmployeeName, 
    CASE 
        WHEN A.FiscalYear < 2015 THEN A.Remaining 
        WHEN B_1.daystaken < 0 THEN A.Remaining + ISNULL(B_1.DaysTaken, 0) 
        ELSE A.Entitlement 
    END AS Remaining
    FROM  dbo.DataLeaveBalance AS A 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.VWLeave_takens AS B_1 
        ON A.FiscalYear = B_1.AffectFY 
        AND A.EmpCode = B_1.EmpCode 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MasterEmployee AS C
        ON A.EmpCode = C.EmpCode
    )
SELECT *,   CASE 
                WHEN CTE.Remaining > 6 THEN 6
                WHEN CTE.Remaining BETWEEN 0 AND 6 THEN CTE.Remaining
                WHEN CTE.Remaining < 0 THEN 0
                ELSE ISNULL(CTE.Remaining,0)
            END AS CF
FROM CTE
```

Comment: still mistake Sir, 

if eva in 2014 have remain 25 and cf 0 then in 2015 eva will have cf 25 or 6. the cf in 2015 take from remain in 2014.

so the CF values in current year will always take from field remain in last year

how if condition like that?, more help you to define what I need.

Comment: Update your question with the data you have so I can help you.